# Spatial interfaces: animating containers back and forth to a sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create a fairly complex animation, where the content resizes into and out of a sidebar. Here's a quick Keynote prototype to explain what I'm after:

[image]

I started using flex-box and changing the flex-direction from row to column, as well as moving the container div into a "sidebar" on the left. However as it turns out, [flex-direction is not animatable.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction)

I then had a look at [Alex Maccaw's Magic Move jQuery plugin](http://blog.alexmaccaw.com/animating-dom-transitions), but I haven't been able to get anywhere with that. Same deal with using absolute positioning and animating the position.

Suggestions on an approach would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gave implementing this a shot using chained [CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations). Here's the result: http://codepen.io/chrisdarroch/full/PNjpaG/

The crux of the solution is to create two sets of elements -- the nav items and the panels -- and then have animations for the base states and "active" states of each.

```
.nav-item {
  animation: grow 1*$n ease-in;
  animation-fill-mode: both;

  &.active {
    animation: fade 0s 1*$n, shrink 1*$n linear 3*$n;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }
}

.panel {
  animation: grow 0*$n linear;
  animation-fill-mode: both;


  &.active {
    animation: appear 0s linear 1*$n, slidein 1*$n ease-out 1*$n;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
  }

  &.inactive {
    animation: shrink 1*$n linear;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
  }
}
```

I've left out the implementations of each `@keyframe` animation for brevity; check the codepen for the full source.

The above is written using [SCSS](http://sass-lang.com/). The important thing to note is the `$n` variable. It's a value in seconds -- e.g., `$n: 0.5s`. It's used to coordinate the delay times and animation times for each stage of the animation.

My solution isn't 100% complete, but you might get an idea for how to chain animations to achieve your design.